# What soft tissue separates bones of toes?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy

I need to know a little about the "knuckles" of toes; specifically the 4 areas that separate the 5 proximal/metatarsal joins.

I'd like to know the terms for areas that might be damaged if the width of the foot were to be repeatedly compressed there. Is there even a name for just the general "knuckle area"?

Thanks

Comment: This question might have a better fit in Biology.SE.

Comment: Could you add a picture pointing to the joint(s) you are talking about? It's hard to tell if you are describing the joints between tarsals and metatarsals or between metatarsals and proximal phalanges.